# Can a java object be accessed from native code and vice versa?

Tags: java, c++, operating-system, java-native-interface

If an object X exists in java heap, and if I knew the address of the object X on java heap, is it possible for the native code to access this object directly from memory without involving JNI? And vice versa, if java code does know the address of object Y on native heap, can java access it without involving JNI?

To be more precise, "Does the java objects gets stored in memory the same way as the native object or is it any different?". If not, wont byteArray objects in java and native gets stored in the same way?

Please provide your suggestions and references.

EDIT: Might be this one is the right question, why do the objects need to be transferred from java heap to native heap through JNI? Why cant the java heap object is accessible to native heap directly?

Comment: no, try to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
java has no pointers like C++, why do you want program this way? what the big task?

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this and bypass JNI? This looks like an [XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can Java code access native objects? No. Java code is managed by the JVM. (More precisely, it's bytecode, not Java code.) The specification of the JVM does not allow bytecode to access arbitrary memory. Bytecode can't even access arbitrary addresses on the JVM heap. For example, private fields can only be accessed by bytecode in the same class.

*Can* native code access JVM heap objects directly (without JNI)? Yes. Native code is running in the same process and address space as the JVM. As far as I know, on most operating systems and hardware platforms this means that native code can do whatever it wants in that address space.

*Should* native code access JVM heap objects directly? Definitely not.

First of all, the JVM specification does not specify the layout of objects on the JVM heap, not even of byte arrays. For example, the JVM may split the array into chunks and transparently translate addresses when bytecode uses the array. If you tried to write native code that accesses the array, you would have to re-implement that translation. Such code may work in one JVM implementation, but probably not in another, or maybe not even in a newer version of the same JVM, or in the same JVM when it runs with a different configuration. That's one reason why you have to use JNI: it gives native code a well-defined "view" of objects on the JVM heap.

Secondly, the JVM garbage collector can move around objects on the heap anytime. Native code should access JVM heap objects through handles. The garbage collector knows about it and updates the handles if necessary. Native code that tries to bypass a handle can never be sure if the object is still there.

A third problem is native code that directly modifies pointers between objects on the JVM heap. Depending on the garbage collector algorithm, this may cause all kinds of problems.

In a nutshell: You probably *could* access JVM heap objects from native code directly, but you almost certainly *shouldn't*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jona.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Other than being a Java/C++ issue, that contradicts with basic OS concepts. Since each process has its own address space, one process cannot reach any object of others.

This limitation can be mitigated only if the process (that tries to reach other's memory) runs in kernel space and the underlying OS allows operations, or some utility like "shared memory" is involved. Even if this were the case, you will face with [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) problem. The same physical portions of memory is addressed with different values in different processes. That's why, if you think that you know the address of an object, this address is virtual and useless in other processes.

**EDIT:** If they are not in different processes, then the answer is definitely yes. Theoretically, you can implement your own JNI :).

Comment: The question is not referring to two different processes. It is just a single java process.

Answer (score -1):

a possible answer is using the APR (Apache Portable Runtime) yeah i know it's JNI based but it have concept of Shared memory. so it's possible to bind a shared memory space created by another program (and vice-versa)

https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__shm.html

ouside of the JNI part, this not seems possible.

Comment: APR has nothing to do with JNI.

Comment: @JonaChristopherSahnwaldt and how do you think the JVM access the .dll or the .so in the APR ?

Comment: Please explain the relation between JVM and APR. I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem like you know what you're talking about.

Comment: look at this part of the APR library : https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__pools.html and please don't forget that object are just "memory structure" ... so YES java can access native object, for that you have to either write a JNI wrapper to a SO or DLL that can access shared memory, after that you have to decode the memory to fit your needs.

Comment: The code you linked to has nothing to do with Java, the JVM, or JNI.

Comment: it lead nowhere to discuss with you, please learn that APR is a library directed to accelerate Tomcat Server (APR IS accessible via JNI and targetted FOR java)

Comment: Well, at least we agree that this discussion didn't get us anywhere. ;-)